# what will be the value of ~(true) in environment? and need answer justification

Tags: c, if-statement, boolean, bitwise-operators, unary-operator

I came across a weird observation recently when I came across below piece of program.

```
// Write C code here

bool abc = true;
bool cba = true;
bool bac = ~abc;

if(cba && bac)
{
    printf("\nYES! %d", bac);
}
else
{
    printf("\nNO! %d", bac);
}
return 0;
```

In the above program, I have observed that even though abc is true, if statement is getting executed and not else. Any explanation would be appreciated.

Note: But the same with " bool bac = !abc;", working as expected.

Comment: What do you think the bitwise-complement of `0b000....0001` will be?

Answer (score 2):

1. The difference between `!` and `~`.

- `!` logical not. Any non-zero value becomes zero and zero becomes `1`
- `~` bitwise not - negates all bits in the bitwise representation of the value. It can be applied to integer values only. `~1` becomes `-2` in two complement integers

C standard 7.16.3:

> The remaining three macros are suitable for use in #if preprocessing
> directives. They are true which expands to the integer constant 1,
> false which expands to the integer constant 0

6.2.5.2

> An object declared as type _Bool is large enough to store the values 0
> and 1.

The smallest type is `char` and it has size (in bits) of `CHAR_BIT` (minimum 8)

Implicit conversions apply:

```
bool abc = true;
bool bac = ~abc;
```

1. `abc` is converted to `int` and has the value `1`
2. `~` operation is applied to the `int` value `1`
3. The result - which is not zero is converted back to bool - and it has value `true` as in `C` language any non-zero value is considered `true`.
4. `bac` has value
   `true`

> what will be the value of ~(true)

It will be an integer and it will have the value of `~1`

The only way to `~` to reverse logical value is to use integer bitfield of size `1`

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned val:1;
}mybool;

int main(void)
{
    mybool abc = {true};
    mybool cba = {true};
    mybool bac = {~abc.val};

    if(cba.val && bac.val)
    {
        printf("\nYES! %u", bac.val);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nNO! %u", bac.val);
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/bjz6T4vTK

Answer (score 1):

The unary operators `!` and `~`  have different effects. From the C Standard (6.5.3.3 Unary arithmetic operators)

> 5 The result of the logical negation operator ! is 0 if the value of
> its operand compares unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand
> compares equal to 0. The result has type int. The expression !E is
> equivalent to (0==E).

So in this line

```
bool bac = !abc;
```

the result of the expression `!abc` is `0`. And this value is assigned to the variable `bac`.

As a result the condition with the logical AND operator in the if statement

```
cba && bac
```

evaluates also to `0`.

> 4 The result of the ~ operator is the bitwise complement of its
> (promoted) operand (that is, each bit in the result is set if and only
> if the corresponding bit in the converted operand is not set). The
> integer promotions are performed on the operand, and the result has
> the promoted type. If the promoted type is an unsigned type, the
> expression ~E is equivalent to the maximum value representable in that
> type minus E.

So in this line

```
bool bac = ~abc;
```

the operand `abc` of the operator `~` is promoted to the type `int` and if `sizeof( int )` is equal to `4` then the result will be `FFFFFFFE` that is not equal to `0`.  Assigning this non-zero expression to the variable `bac`makes the variable equal to `1`.

As a result the condition with the logical AND operator

```
cba && bac
```

also will be equal to 1.